# MySQL PHP 'Filter' for Services

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I've been racking my brain all day trying to figure this one out! I'm hoping you guys can help.

I'm building a PHP system which will filter out records for 'Suppliers' within a MySQL table.

The services are stored in a table as such:

```
id
service
```

The suppliers are stored in a table as such:

```
id
company_name
```

Then after much reading, I added an additional table, which links the suppliers, to their corresponding services:

```
id
supplier_id
service_id
```

One supplier can offer many services.

When a user clicks on a filter (span tags which have jQuery on clicks, which capture the id of the service clicked), I want to display the suppliers which offer that service. When a user clicks an additional service, I want to display only the suppliers that offer both of those services. And so on...

I am struggling to establish a) is this the correct way forward, and b) what the SQL would be for it. At the moment, I pass the additional service ID to PHP using $.GET, and store a string of them all as a CSV in Session variables.

Many thanks in advance,

James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. > is this the correct way forward

   Seems sound to me, so far.
2. > what the SQL would be for it

   To get the details of all those suppliers that supply *both* service id 4 *and* service id 7, you could first *join* the tables then *group* them by supplier and *filter* the resulting groups for those that contain the desired matches:

   ```sql
   SELECT   p.*
   FROM     suppliers         p
       JOIN supplier_services a ON a.supplier_id = p.id
   GROUP BY p.id
   HAVING   SUM(a.service_id = 4)
        AND SUM(a.service_id = 7)
   ```

   To improve the performance of this query, you could throw in a `WHERE a.service_id IN (4,7)`—this would be particularly beneficial if there is an index on `supplier_services(supplier_id, service_id)`.

Comment: You, are a genius. Thank you very much. Works a charm!